# For cycle bugged?

Tags: c++, for-loop, cycle

I made a for cycle to calculate the population of an alien species growth. This is the cycle:

```
int mind = 96;
int aliens = 1;
for (int i=0; i <= mind; i++)
{
    aliens = aliens * 2; 
}
cout << aliens;
```

Oddly, the `cout` is returning `0`, and it makes no sense, it should return a very high value. Is the cycle badly coded?

Comment: where is this returning `0`?

Comment: every time i cout aliens it returns 0

Comment: how do you count aliens? please show us.

Comment: By the way, have you calculated the correct number?

Comment: as an FYI 2^96 is one HUGE number, probably not what you intend

Comment: well the aliens starts at 1, and then for 96 times the aliens value is doubled for each alien, something like that

Comment: I doubt this value would fit in a `long` or even a `long long`.

Comment: i didnt calculate it myself, in actually making a program to do it, and this is the program... but it returns 0

Comment: ohh so th number is too long... how do i make it appear on the screen then???

Comment: You are trying to compute `2^96`.  a 32bit integer only store up to `2^31 - 1`

Comment: so there is no way of showing it?

Comment: You can't. even long long max value is 2^63 -1.

Comment: I think it's safe to state the answer should be -1 in a signed 96-bit env.

Comment: aw ok... thanks for the explaining :(

Comment: @elmnt57: You can show it, but you'll need a container big enough, at least 96 bit. You can also write one yourself. Reminds me of homework by the way.

Comment: the reason you get zero is because you have overflowed the capacity of int, the number you are trying to compute is several orders of magnitude larger that the number of atoms in the universe

Comment: You'll find that alien reproduction tails off as the population density increases and resources are more contested.  That's a problem with your model; you need more realistic aliens.

Comment: @elmnt57 Use [boost::multiprecision](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c47e40730d06e2c), or another big integer library.

Comment: @Toby Basically no problem if each new alien is spawned in a different parallel universe. But they might commit suicide because of solitude then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simple. you have a `int` (most likely 32-bit signed integer). The operation you're doing (x2 each cycle) can be expressed as a *shift arithmetic left*.
Beware the powers of 2! Doing 1 << 31 on a 32-bit signed integer will effectively go back to 0 (after an overflow).

Let's see how your loop goes.

```
0 2
1 4
2 8
3 16
4 32
5 64
6 128
7 256
8 512
9 1024
10 2048
11 4096
12 8192
13 16384
14 32768
15 65536
16 131072
17 262144
18 524288
19 1048576
20 2097152
21 4194304
22 8388608
23 16777216
24 33554432
25 67108864
26 134217728
27 268435456
28 536870912
29 1073741824
30 -2147483648 // A.K.A. overflow
31 0
```

At this point I don't think I need to tell you `0 x 2 = 0`
The point being: use a double or a integer variable that's at least `mind + 1` bits long